# Can't load content from site via URL connection

Tags: java, html, url

I am trying to load site http://www.povarenok.ru/ from url connection, but content is empty. I tried with other sites - all works. Please help, what's wrong with this site?

```
    URL url;

    try {

        url = new URL("http://www.povarenok.ru/");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;

        String fileName = "c:\\test.html";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        //inputLine is empty!!! All works with other sites
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bw.write(inputLine);
        }

        bw.close();
        br.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to :

```
 url = new URL("http://www.povarenok.ru");
                                       ^ - no slash here
```

looks like this site has configured `/` to someother purposes

[edit]

checked again and this slash is really not the case, from what I see it starts to work after changing urser-agent (put this before BufferedReader creation):

```
((HttpURLConnection)conn).setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "SO");
```

---

hints on how to debug such problems on [Windows with Fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurejavaapp) :

you should first install `fiddler2` - it will allow you to view your requests. In your java app, add following lines on app start:

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
```

now, suppose you have a site that loads in webbrowser, but does not load in your java app. You must compare request headers and find differences. So you load your page in webbrowser, and later in your app, and using fiddler compare results.